# Как синхронизировать коммиты между Azure и Github

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, azure

Есть проект в dev.azure.com, хочу чтобы вся история коммитов также была и на github. Попробовал импортировать репозиторий, все сработало. Дальше работал над кодом в Azure, как мне сделать так, чтобы коммиты синхронизировались с github?
Все операции производил через интерфейс Visual Studio

Comment: То что вам нужно называется зеркалированием (mirroring). Не знаю как у Azure и Github, у GitLab это настраивается в три клика.